# Go - os/exec on Windows - obtaining process handle

Tags: windows, go, process, exec

From a Go program, I want to execute another process to execute some work. After the execution is done, I can use [os.ProcessState](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ProcessState.SysUsage) to get the resource info. On *ux systems, this includes memory usage, but on Windows it doesn't.

The [go-winio](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Microsoft/go-winio) package provides access to the [GetProcessMemoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo)  syscall, which returns this info.

The problem is - to specify the process, you need to specify the `windows.Handle` to the process. However, typically processes in Go are identified by PIDs, not handles. The `os.Process` type has a public `Pid` field, but the `handle` is private, used internally by the package code.

Is there a way to bridge the gap between `pid` and `windows.Handle`?

I know I can do [windows.OpenProcess](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#OpenProcess) for the child process - and it works. But the child process may be a short lived process and that's a data race.

There is the option of just porting all of the work done by `os/exec` and doing [syscall.StartProcess](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#StartProcess) - that way I get the handle directly. But that all seems doing a lot of work where 99.9% of functionality is the same. I'm not against the work, I'm just unsure if it's the right approach.